# Click on search icon on actionbar in Android?

Tags: android

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
                .getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

i got error

```
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                    .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

this like my error is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
                                                                                           at com.domore.navigationdrawersliddingmenu.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:136)
```

Please, help me solve out this error

Comment: Your `searchManager` object is not getting initialized

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step and should work and you can find the [official](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) doc

***menu.xml***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@+id/search"
              android:title="@string/search_title"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
              android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
              android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
    </menu>
```

***Manifest***

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivty" 
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

***searchable.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="Hint"
    android:label="Label"></searchable>
```

*And in **Activty** override as below*

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
           (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
          String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
          // Do work using string
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind efforts for me i am really satisfied with your answer.you done a great job thanx a lot